# Drawing different 2D shapes on div/canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to draw 2d shapes (Rectangle, polygon, line, arrow, dash line, circle) on a div which contains image with fix dimensions.

I found several links/libraries in javascript which allowed this. In my case I also need the coordinates/points (attribute of shapes) of the shape drawn on the image for further saving into some file and processing.

Later when we access the same web page it should fetch all the shape details from the saved file and show it already drawn so user can resize/change it and save it again.

Is there any library which allows such functionality?

I appreciate your input about any link, reference, article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across below libraries which is best suited to my requirements,

http://jsvectoreditor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

http://kineticjs.com/

More links are listed below,

http://raphaeljs.com/

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/creating-predefined-shapes/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm

Hope somebody searching for similar thing find this answer helpful in resolving their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas API is fairly low level and once an image has been drawn upon the canvas it is not possible to introspect the object drawn. Think of the canvas element as a bitmap which is edited by drawing operations.

You may want to checkout [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) which provides an intuitive object model on top of canvas API.